# How do I add or display the product price in woocommerce thankyou page?

Tags: php, woocommerce

For example, 2 x $12 =$ 24. I want to display the $12 in thankyou page after the user place the order.

The code is in the order-details-item.php. For default woocommerce thankyou page, they don't display the product unit price. Is there a way to display it? This the woocommerce default code from order-details-item.php. Can someone help me?

```
if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
  return;
}
?>
<tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
 <td class="product-name">
    <?php
        $is_visible = $product && $product->is_visible();

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $is_visible ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ) : $item['name'], $item, $is_visible );
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong>', $item );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

        $order->display_item_meta( $item );
        $order->display_item_downloads( $item );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
    ?>
  </td>
  <td class="product-total">
    <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <?php if ( $order->has_status( array( 'completed', 'processing' ) ) && (  $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_purchase_note', true ) ) ) : ?>
 <tr class="product-purchase-note">
  <td colspan="3"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
 </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The price is displayed on this line`<?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>` What do you want it to say instead?

Comment: Looks like they are supplying you with $item['qty'].... couldn't you just divide the total by that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

```
echo $_product->get_price_html();
```

That will display the unit price for that line item.